# How should I unit test middleware packages with gorilla context

Tags: testing, go

I have this net/http server setup with several middleware in a chain and I can't find examples on how I should test these...

I am using basic net/http with the gorilla/mux router and one Handle looks somewhat like this:

```
r.Handle("/documents", addCors(checkAPIKey(getDocuments(sendJSON)))).Methods("GET")
```

In these I aggregate some data and supply them via Gorilla Context context.Set methods.

Usually I test my http functions with httptest, and I hope to do it with these as well but I can't figure out how and I am curious as to what is the best way. Should I test each middleware seperately? Should I prefill the appropriate context values then when they are needed? Can I test this entire chain at once so I can just check desired states on input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not test anything involving Gorilla or any other 3rd party package.  If you want to test to make sure it works, i'd setup some external test runner or integration suite for the endpoints of a running version of your app (e.g. a C.I. server).

Instead, test your Middleware and Handlers individually - as those you have control over.

But, if you are set on testing the stack (mux -> handler -> handler -> handler -> MyHandler), this is where defining the middleware globally using *functions as vars* could help:

```
var addCors = func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
  ...
}

var checkAPIKey = func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
  ...
}
```

During normal use, their implementation remains the same with change.

```
r.Handle("/documents", addCors(checkAPIKey(getDocuments(sendJSON)))).Methods("GET")
```

But for unit testing, you can override them:

```
// important to keep the same package name for
// your test file, so you can get to the private
// vars.
package main

import (
  "testing"
)

func TestXYZHandler(t *testing.T) {

  // save the state, so you can restore at the end
  addCorsBefore := addCors
  checkAPIKeyBefore := checkAPIKey

  // override with whatever customization you want
  addCors = func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return h
  }
  checkAPIKey = func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return h
  }

  // arrange, test, assert, etc.
  //

  // when done, be a good dev and restore the global state
  addCors = addCorsBefore
  checkAPIKey = checkAPIKeyBefore
}
```

If you find yourself copy-n-pasting this boiler plate code often, move it to a global pattern within your unit tests:

```
package main

import (
  "testing"
)

var (
  addCorsBefore = addCors
  checkAPIKeyBefore = checkAPIKey
)

func clearMiddleware() {
  addCors = func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return h
  }
  checkAPIKey = func(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return h
  }
}

func restoreMiddleware() {
  addCors = addCorsBefore
  checkAPIKey = checkAPIKeyBefore
}

func TestXYZHandler(t *testing.T) {

  clearMiddleware()

  // arrange, test, assert, etc.
  //

  restoreMiddleware()
}
```

A side note on unit testing end points...

Since middleware should operate with sensible defaults (expected to pass normally and not mutex state of the underlying stream of data you want to test in func), I advise to unit test the middleware outside of the context of your actual main Handler function.

That way, you have one set of unit tests strictly for your middleware.  And another set of tests focusing purely on the primary Handler of the url you are calling.  It makes discovering the code much easier for newcomers.